# Java Spring MVC Template Project Problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception

Brand new project that I just created using the Spring Template for MVC. I try to run on Server and get the following.

Any ideas?

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/src]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 25 more
Jan 15, 2013 10:27:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor /Users/maratlevit/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE/base-instance/conf/Catalina/localhost/src.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/src]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

**EDIT:** Looking at the Markers tab I see the following:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: '/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar' in project 'FirstLesson' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file   FirstLesson     Build path  Build Path Problem
```

**EDIT 2:** Added list of dependencies as requested:

```
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.10/aspectjrt-1.6.10.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.6/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar
/Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.7/junit-4.7.jar
```

Comment: Can you provide a list of your dependencies? Also, are you deploying it within eclipse?

Comment: Your dependencies look good to me. Please see the answer I just provided and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would check is:

Project -> right click -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Make sure "Maven Dependencies" is in that list.

Second test:

Project -> right click -> properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Make sure that "Maven Dependencies" is in that list as a source. Then, make sure that the Deploy Path corresponding to it is correct. I typically make my deploy path {project}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's all normal. Looking at the error log I'm seeing: `Invalid ZIP archive: /Users/maratlevit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: @mlevit before I look much further into this, can you try deleting your repositories folder and everything underneath it. Then run a new Maven clean install. It's reaching, but it could be a bad download.

Comment: @mlevit Also, there is a Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE now. Try upgrading.

Comment: Maven was installed with Sping via their installer. I'll try removing everything that it installed including Maven etc and re-installing again.

Comment: @mlevit You don't need to uninstall Maven - just remove your repositories and allow Maven to download them again.

Comment: @mlevit Also, please try changing:   <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version> to   <org.springframework-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>

Comment: No idea what happened. I uninstalled... deleted all directories including Maven and re-installed. Just worked!

Comment: :) I assumed this was the problem. Maybe at one point, you had downloaded a faulty version of the spring jar. If it had existed in your .m2/repositories before, it would not download the same version again. Re-downloading it must have given you a proper jar. Please mark this response as your answer! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Need more specific information : Is it a  maven project? Are all jars added to the project?

Factors which may cause the  `ClassNotFound` exception :

1. Jars are not added to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory
2. DispatcherServlet reference is not configured properly in web.xml

Can you upload the web.xml, spring xml, project structure and verify the information above?

Comment: It is a maven project. It's a brand new project... I haven't done any changes to it since I created. Why would jars not be added if it's a brand new project?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that your class path is setup correctly, thats why you are getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

Check its correct, and that all your jars are in the correct place.